# psycopg2 package error while installing odoo12 enterprise version on ubuntu18

Tags: psycopg2, odoo-12, failed-installation

I am trying to install odoo12 enterprise version on ubuntu18.

I have the deb file, and using gdebi to install the package.

But installation fails with the error

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of odoo:

odoo depends on python3-psycopg2; however:

Package python3-psycopg2 is not installed.

I have tried installing psycopg2.8.5, 2.8.3, 2.7.7 and 2.7.3.1  manually using pip3 install. But with all these , I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Run this cmd:

**Step 1**
Run update command to update package repositories and get the latest package information.

> sudo apt-get update -y

**Step 2**
Run the install command with -y flag to quickly install the packages and dependencies.

> sudo apt-get install -y python3-psycopg2

Execute - `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: Tried this already. But getting python error  "python3-psycopg2 : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed". My python version is 3.6.9

Comment: i;ve edite the answer after the execute the cmd try with step 2 without -y.